# Tooltip display content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tooltip display content how to show as below format

Please help me

"Dynamic_value" values are coming from function in variable and i want to display
as below format

> **Selection Parameters**
>
> Selection Date - Dynamic_value
>
> Unit Value- Dynamic_value
>
> list - Dynamic_value

below is example of code

```html
<label id="lblName" for="txtName" title="Full Name">Name</label>
<input id="txtName" type="text" title="Your full name as it appears in paasport" />

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>tooltip demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtName').tooltip({
      content: toolTipFunction

    });

    function toolTipFunction() {
      var texdisp = 'Selection Date - Dynamic_value; Unit Value- Dynamic_value; list - Dynamic_value';
      return texdisp
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. please consider renaming this question to something more specific. or descriptive.

Comment: Hi, please include the 'dynamic data'/'dynamic value' you mentioned in your question.

Comment: this is sample code in variable var texdisp ='Selection Date - Dynamic_value; Unit Value- Dynamic_value; list - Dynamic_value';

Comment: Where is this dynamic value coming from? You say "from function in variable" which is meaningless without context. Please [edit] your question to include where the data are defined. Also; you may want to do some research into "string concatenation" in JavaScript.

Comment: below is function im getting the Dynamic values i give a example
function toolTipFunction() {
      var texdisp = 'Selection Date - Dynamic_value; Unit Value- Dynamic_value; list - Dynamic_value';
      return texdisp
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you're just struggling to include line breaks where you want them. This can be done simply by including `<br />` elements in the `texdisp` string.

```html
<label id="lblName" for="txtName" title="Full Name">Name</label>
<input id="txtName" type="text" title="Your full name as it appears in paasport" />

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>tooltip demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtName').tooltip({
      content: toolTipFunction
    });

    function toolTipFunction() {
      var texdisp = 'Selection Date - Dynamic_value;<br /><br /> Unit Value- Dynamic_value;<br /><br /> list - Dynamic_value';
      return texdisp
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for ur help 
i'm new to javascript and jquery , 
can we use html code in that